# use grpc on dotnet/core/runtime-deps:2.2-alpine3.9 got symbol not found error

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, grpc

I have used grpc in my .netcore program and I want to build a docker image to use it.

this is how I build my program in dockerfile

```
RUN  dotnet publish -r linux-musl-x64 --no-restore -c Release -o /out
```

And I copy to other images as my images like

```
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["./MyService"]
```

The question is about the runtime image. If I use "microsoft/dotnet:2.2-runtime-deps-alpine" there is no problem, BUT if using "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime-deps:2.2-alpine3.9"

I got an error message.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Error loading native library "/app/libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.so". Symbol not found: PAL_dlerror
at Grpc.Core.Internal.UnmanagedLibrary..ctor(String[] libraryPathAlternatives)
at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadUnmanagedLibrary()
at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadNativeMethods()
at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension..ctor()
at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.Get()
at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.GrpcNativeInit()
at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment..ctor()
at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.AddRef()
at Grpc.Core.Server..ctor(IEnumerable`1 options)
at MyService.Program.Main(String[] args) in /code/MyService/Program.cs:line 32
```

How can I fix this? What's the difference between these two images? I can only find the second one`s Dockerfile on [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-runtime-deps/)

Comment: After some test, I found if image "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime-deps" tag change from 2.2-alpine3.9 to 2.2-alpine3.8 , it's totally fine. Seems the problem is related to the alpine 3.9 ?